# Is it possible to use Gmail filters to mute a conversation?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, mute

I've tried using a filter to skip the Inbox, but when someone else replies to the original email it ends up in the Inbox again.

Comment: Did you try using the "mute conversation" feature?

Comment: What I am trying to avoid is having to hit mute conversation on every conversation that fits the filter criteria. That's why I want to use filters. Unfortunately it looks like Gmail Filters do not support mute.

Comment: Is it not possible to extend your filter to include the replies?

Comment: "Skip the Inbox" should work. What are you filtering on?

Comment: @ale "Skip the Inbox" would work for the first email, but any reply to the thread would bring it back to the Inbox

Answer (score 6):

You are correct, it is not possible to use a filter to mute conversations.